# Load separate view to slide into current view using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm working with a test project now on PHP using CodeIgniter and I've chosen a parallax template. The template includes a separate HTML file that slides open when the link is clicked.

Now what I've been facing here is that, how could I load the separate view to slide open in the main view? The separate view requires to load some data from my database. Here is a part of the main view which calls the sub sliding view.

*The `data-project="works/gallery.html"` is the separate view that slides open after clicking the `<h3>gallery post</h3>`.

```
<div class="item hoveritem" data-project="works/gallery.html">
  <a href="#" class="link">
    <div class="hovercontent">
      <h3>gallery post</h3>
      <h1>by admin</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
  <img class="lazyOwl" src="img/work/006.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was so dumb of me too post my question here without trying my very best first. I've already resolved the issue by using another controller that manages the separate views. Below is a sample code that I use on the controller that made it work. XD

*controller

```
class Works extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
}

function gallery() {
    $this->load->view('works/gallery');
}
}
```

*And here is the main view that I use to slide open the separate view

```
<div class="item hoveritem" data-project="works/gallery">
    <a href="#" class="link">
        <div class="hovercontent">
            <h3>gallery post</h3>
            <h1>by admin</h1>
        </div>
    </a>
    <img class="lazyOwl" src="resource/img/work/002.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: You need not loading a separate , you just need to hide and show, then create a server sided request at the backend to load the data from database loading request like ajax get or post.